# WCF Health Monitoring similar to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, was, health-monitoring

ASP.NET has a nice feature called Health Monitoring. Once defined in `system.web/healthMonitoring` section we get very useful web events to log/analyze. Are there any similar means for WCF services that don't use ASP.NET compatibility mode and hosted under IIS7/WAS ?

**Update:** What i've found out is that enabling system.web/healthMonitoring in WCF service's web.config allows to get some of web events: System.Web.HttpRuntime, 1002, "Application is shutting down. Reason: Configuration changed.". No heartbeats and others. I don't understand how that works if ASP.NET is not involved in the process but that's the fact.

Answer (score -1):

You can add some configuration to the config file of the client and will have a lot of logging information. check the below links

- [link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx)
- [link2](http://mkdot.net/blogs/dejan/archive/2008/10/23/wcf-tracing-and-message-logging.aspx)

Comment: Not what i exactly meant, sorry. This is regular WCF logging, i can't get heart beats and app pool recycling events with it, can i?

Comment: @UserControl: a WCF service doesn't typically "live" all the time - the service class is instantiated to handle a request, and freed once the response is sent back - so there's really nothing to "monitor" most of the time...

Comment: If WCF service is hosted by IIS/WAS it's recycled and activated by request the same way as regular ASP.NET application, isn't it?

Comment: @UserControl: **NO** - it's not the WCF **service** that's dealt with by the IIS/WAS - but the **service host** - not the same thing!